# Database Design - Writing something about existing user or not existing user or General

Tags: database-design

I am developing a site some thing related to mothers . Any body can register to the site and **can write about his mother or general comments about mother**

1) Mother also can be part of the users ( registered users table)

2) If she doesn't exist in registered users table user has to write his mothers name

3) Not related to his mother, just write some generic topic about mothers

**users table :-**

```
 `user_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `user_name` varchar(25) CHARACTER SET latin1 NOT NULL,
  `surname` varchar(30) CHARACTER SET latin1 NOT NULL,
  `name` varchar(30) CHARACTER SET latin1 NOT NULL,
```

**About mothers table ( 1st case) :-**

```
  `id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `mother_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,  ( user_id of the above table)
  `subject` varchar(150) NOT NULL,
  `details` text NOT NULL,
```

The above table deals with if the mother exists in the system

**About mothers table ( 2nd case) :-**

```
  `id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `mother_name` varchar(50) unsigned NOT NULL,  
  `subject` varchar(150) NOT NULL,
  `details` text NOT NULL,
```

The above table deals with if the mother doesn't exist in the system

**About mothers table (3rd case) :-**

```
  `id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `subject` varchar(150) NOT NULL,
  `details` text NOT NULL,
```

The above table deals with if it is generic about mother

**Now to show the distinct list of mothers ( recent ones first , not details about mothers )**

I have to join first mothers table with users table to get the names and have to union with 2nd mothers table and have descending it by date .

**If I have to show details about mothers**

I have union three tables descending by date

Some how I think I am making this complicated .

If I combine three tables into one table , ID will be Null for which doesn't exist and ID and Mother's name will be null if it is a generic comment . Could some one give me best design approach for this ?

Thank You

Regards

Kiran

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since a mother can also be a user, and assuming each child can write at most one comment about their mother, it looks like you need something like this:

[image]

You'll need to constrain the NULLability of certain fields, to ensure that if a person has mother, that person is a registered user (has user name) and the subject and description are present:

```
CHECK (
    (MOTHER_ID IS NULL AND MOTHER_SUBJECT IS NULL AND MOTHER_DETAILS IS NULL)
    OR (USER_NAME IS NOT NULL AND MOTHER_ID IS NOT NULL AND MOTHER_SUBJECT IS NOT NULL AND MOTHER_DETAILS IS NOT NULL)
)
```

To get all persons who are also mothers, you can do something like this:

```
SELECT *
FROM PERSON T1
WHERE EXISTS (
    SELECT *
    FROM PERSON T2
    WHERE T1.PERSON_ID = T2.MOTHER_ID
)
```

In plain English: select those persons who are mothers to at least one person.

You'll need an index on MOTHER_ID for optimal execution of this query (some databases automatically create indexes on foreign keys).

#### --- EDIT ---

If user can write many memories about the mother, the design could look like this:

[image]

Unfortunately, this does allow for a situation where a non-user writes memories. If you absolutely have to avoid that, either use a database that can employ an NULL-able UNIQUE constrain as a parent endpoint of the foreign key and use USER_NAME instead of PERSON_ID to connect tables, or if you don't mind some complication, do this:

[image]

The symbol: [image] denotes category (a.k.a. inheritance, generalization hierarchy etc.), but there is a twist in this particular model: a PERSON can be both USER and MOTHER (i.e. this is so called "non-discriminating" category).

Comment: Thanks Four response . Sorry If my question was confusing .. If the mother is not there in the system user should provide her name and give details . In the above design you mentioned I can not write my memories with mother more than once . The user should be able to write as many as comments ( Or memories) about his mother

Comment: @Bujji When you say: _"If the mother is not there in the system user should provide her name and give details."_, I'm not sure what's the problem, please clarify. As for multiple memories, see my edit.

Comment: Thanks for your update . To your questions , I mean if the mother is not an user of the system . For example my mother is no more and she can not be in the system and for around 70% of the mothers of 50 years old people mothers are not knowing computers and they can not be in the system . So that time I just giver name and write some memories about her . Thanks .. Kiran

Comment: @Bujji That's why USER_NAME is NULL-able (in the first two models) and you don't have to insert both USER and MOTHER in the last one. Mothers are still persons and you'll have to track the appropriate information _somehow_. The models I have shown enable you to avoid repeating common fields in case mother is also user, but do not require that _all_ mothers must be users. When you enter a mother's name, you'll have to search through existing mothers and see if one of them can be "reused", or new person inserted. But you should think if just name/surname is enough for that.

Comment: Thanks for updating and giving me this design .